# Problems reading json data with jquery (chat application)

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, chat

i have a problem with reading JSON data.

**model.php**

```
class chatApp extends database{


public $row = array();
public function IO(){

    //SELECTING FROM DATABASE MAKE QUERY ....

     $this->row = $mysql->show; //result

     return $this->row; //return it


}}
```

**controller.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['showmessage'])){

$chatApp = new chatApp(); // chat app object

$row = $chatApp->IO();
echo json_encode($row);} // echo it like json
```

**view.php**

```
function update(){

     $.ajax({  
          type: "POST",  
           url: " http://localhost/chat/controller.php?showmessage", 
           dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data) {  

            $("#chat").html(data); //The data ?



       }  
   });    
 } setInterval (update, 1000);
```

So the problem is that i can't show the data in the chat div ? what am i making wrong

Comment: What happens when you visit controller.php in your browser? Are you seeing any JSON outputted?

Comment: how are you calling the update() function in your javascript?

Comment: @TomWalters yes im seen teh JSON : 
[{"id":"1","message":"sdvsvdsdv","nickname":""}]

Comment: @Austin setInterval (update, 1000);

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
$("#chat").html(jQuery.parseJSON(data));
```

or use `getJSON` instead of `ajax`:

```
function update(){
    $.getJSON("http://localhost/chat/controller.php?showmessage",
        function(data) {
         $("#chat").html(data);
         setTimeout(update,1000);
    });
}
setTimeout(update,1000);
```

use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`

Comment: shouldn't matter, as his datatype is set to json